# La sintaxis del comando no es correcta

Tags: nodejs, npm, cmd, terminal, instalacion

Tengo un problema con npm, cuando terminó de instalar node js(que viene con npm) parece que va todo perfecto hasta que verifico en la terminal(Windows 10, 64 bit).
Cuando escribo `node --version` funciona sin problemas pero cuando escribo `npm --version` me sale

```
la sintaxis del comando no es correcta.
la sintaxis del comando no es correcta.
la sintaxis del comando no es correcta.
No sé esperaba /f en este momento.
```

Este código aparece cada vez que en la terminal pongo npm primero. No es un problema de programación en si, sino de instalación para programar y no encontré nada en internet, reinstale Nodejs 2 veces y el problema persiste. Por lo que vi los archivos de npm se encuentran. Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata esto

1. Tipea **regedit** en cmd
2. Entra a **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor**
3. Aqui veras una llave llamada **EnableExtensions**
4. Cambiala a **1**

Aqui es donde hablan de este problema

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/379

Comment: SOS UN ÍDOLO, no sabes cómo estaba sufriendo con ese problema, ahora le cuesta un poquito pero nada. Mil gracias ahora puedo seguir el curso de Coursera, mucha suerte!

Comment: Me alegra escucharlo, buena suerte en el resto del curso