# La sintaxis del comando no es correcta al utilizar mvn -v

Tags: java, cmd, maven, windows10

Estoy tratando de instalar maven en windows 10, he descargado el archivo binario (https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz)
y configurado todas las variables de entorno necesarias:

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311

MAVEN_HOME = C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar\apache-maven-3.8.4

y la ruta al bin en PATH:%MAVEN_HOME%\bin

Al utilizar mvn -v o mvn --version (o cualquier otro comando que comience con mvn), en la consola solo aparece "La sintaxis del comando no es correcta", pero no aparece ningún tipo de error a parte de esto.

Al utilizar `where mvn` se obtienen las siguientes líneas:

```
C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin\mvn 
C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin\mvn.cmd
```

Al escribir `@echo on` y ejecutar mvn.cmd, este es el resultado:

```
C:\Users\usuario>mvn.cmd

C:\Users\usuario>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPre

C:\Users\usuario>if exist "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.bat"

C:\Users\usuario>if exist "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.cmd"

C:\Users\usuario>set ERROR_CODE=0
La sintaxis del comando no es correcta.

C:\Users\usuario>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311
"=="" goto OkJHome

C:\Users\usuario>
```

El codigo de mvn.cmd:

```
@REM Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
@REM or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
@REM distributed with this work for additional information
@REM regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
@REM to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
@REM "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
@REM with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
@REM
@REM    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
@REM
@REM Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
@REM software distributed under the License is distributed on an
@REM "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
@REM KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
@REM specific language governing permissions and limitations
@REM under the License.

@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Apache Maven Startup Script
@REM
@REM Environment Variable Prerequisites
@REM
@REM   JAVA_HOME          Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
@REM   MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO  (Optional) Set to 'on' to enable the echoing of the batch commands.
@REM   MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE (Optional) set to 'on' to wait for a key stroke before ending.
@REM   MAVEN_OPTS        (Optional) Java runtime options used when Maven is executed.
@REM   MAVEN_SKIP_RC     (Optional) Flag to disable loading of mavenrc files.
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@REM Begin all REM lines with '@' in case MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO is 'on'
@echo on
@REM enable echoing my setting MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO to 'on'
@if "%MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO%"=="on" echo %MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO%

@REM Execute a user defined script before this one
if not "%MAVEN_SKIP_RC%"=="" goto skipRcPre
@REM check for pre script, once with legacy .bat ending and once with .cmd ending
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.bat" %*
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd" %*
:skipRcPre

@setlocal

set ERROR_CODE=0

@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto OkJHome
for %%i in (java.exe) do set "JAVACMD=%%~$PATH:i"
goto checkJCmd

:OkJHome
set "JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

:checkJCmd
if exist "%JAVACMD%" goto chkMHome

echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, >&2
echo this environment variable is needed to run this program. >&2
goto error

:chkMHome
set "MAVEN_HOME=%~dp0"
set "MAVEN_HOME=%MAVEN_HOME:~0,-5%"
if not "%MAVEN_HOME%"=="" goto checkMCmd
goto error

:checkMCmd
if exist "%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\mvn.cmd" goto init
goto error
@REM ==== END VALIDATION ====

:init

set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

@REM Find the project basedir, i.e., the directory that contains the directory ".mvn".
@REM Fallback to current working directory if not found.

set "MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=%MAVEN_BASEDIR%"
if not "%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%"=="" goto endDetectBaseDir

set "EXEC_DIR=%CD%"
set "WDIR=%EXEC_DIR%"

@REM Look for the --file switch and start the search for the .mvn directory from the specified
@REM POM location, if supplied.

set FILE_ARG=
:arg_loop
if "%~1" == "-f" (
  set "FILE_ARG=%~2"
  shift
  goto process_file_arg
)
if "%~1" == "--file" (
  set "FILE_ARG=%~2"
  shift
  goto process_file_arg
)
@REM If none of the above, skip the argument
shift
if not "%~1" == "" (
  goto arg_loop
) else (
  goto findBaseDir
)

:process_file_arg
if "%FILE_ARG%" == "" (
  goto findBaseDir
)
if not exist "%FILE_ARG%" (
  echo POM file "%FILE_ARG%" specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist >&2
  goto error
)
if exist "%FILE_ARG%\*" (
  set "POM_DIR=%FILE_ARG%"
) else (
  call :get_directory_from_file "%FILE_ARG%"
)
if not exist "%POM_DIR%" (
  echo Directory "%POM_DIR%" extracted from the -f/--file command-line argument "%FILE_ARG%" does not exist >&2
  goto error
)
set "WDIR=%POM_DIR%"
goto findBaseDir

:get_directory_from_file
set "POM_DIR=%~dp1"
:stripPomDir
if not "_%POM_DIR:~-1%"=="_\" goto pomDirStripped
set "POM_DIR=%POM_DIR:~0,-1%"
goto stripPomDir
:pomDirStripped
exit /b

:findBaseDir
cd /d "%WDIR%"
:findBaseDirLoop
if exist "%WDIR%\.mvn" goto baseDirFound
cd ..
IF "%WDIR%"=="%CD%" goto baseDirNotFound
set "WDIR=%CD%"
goto findBaseDirLoop

:baseDirFound
set "MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=%WDIR%"
cd /d "%EXEC_DIR%"
goto endDetectBaseDir

:baseDirNotFound
if "_%EXEC_DIR:~-1%"=="_\" set "EXEC_DIR=%EXEC_DIR:~0,-1%"
set "MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=%EXEC_DIR%"
cd /d "%EXEC_DIR%"

:endDetectBaseDir

set "jvmConfig=\.mvn\jvm.config"
if not exist "%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%%jvmConfig%" goto endReadAdditionalConfig

@setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%\.mvn\jvm.config") do set JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS=!JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS! %%a
@endlocal & set JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS=%JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS%

:endReadAdditionalConfig

for %%i in ("%MAVEN_HOME%"\boot\plexus-classworlds-*) do set CLASSWORLDS_JAR="%%i"
set CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

"%JAVACMD%" ^
  %JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS% ^
  %MAVEN_OPTS% ^
  %MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS% ^
  -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% ^
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" ^
  "-Dmaven.home=%MAVEN_HOME%" ^
  "-Dlibrary.jansi.path=%MAVEN_HOME%\lib\jansi-native" ^
  "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%" ^
  %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
goto end

:error
set ERROR_CODE=1

:end
@endlocal & set ERROR_CODE=%ERROR_CODE%

if not "%MAVEN_SKIP_RC%"=="" goto skipRcPost
@REM check for post script, once with legacy .bat ending and once with .cmd ending
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_post.bat" call "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_post.bat"
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_post.cmd" call "%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_post.cmd"
:skipRcPost

@REM pause the script if MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE is set to 'on'
if "%MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE%"=="on" pause

if "%MAVEN_TERMINATE_CMD%"=="on" exit %ERROR_CODE%

cmd /C exit /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

Tanto mvn como mvn.cmd generan el mismo resultado.

Otras cosas que he probado:
Crear variable de usuario MAVEN_HOME y añadir a PATH en usuario y crear variable de sistema MAVEN_HOME y añadir a PATH de sistema. Genera la misma línea sobre la sintaxis del comando.
Ejecutar desde cmd y desde powershell: Ambas dan la misma línea “La sintaxis del comando no es correcta”.
Ejecutar cmd como administrador: de obtiene la misma línea.
Eliminar y volver a descargar maven, tanto la versión 3.8.4 como otras versiones anteriores y volver a configurar todas las variables, todas han tenido el mismo resultado.
La solución dada en [La sintaxis del comando no es correcta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385667/la-sintaxis-del-comando-no-es-correcta) tampoco ha cambiado el resultado

Ninguna de estas soluciona el error.

Comment: wue te sale al correr `where mvn`?

Comment: Salen las siguientes lineas: C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin\mvn
C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin\mvn.cmd

Comment: y si le pones `mvn.cmd install`?

Comment: También sale "La sintaxis del comando no es correcta."

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [La sintaxis del comando no es correcta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385667/la-sintaxis-del-comando-no-es-correcta)

Comment: Tu problema es el mismo que el de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385667/la-sintaxis-del-comando-no-es-correcta

Comment: Ya probé a cambiarlo pero tampoco funcionó

Comment: @E.Betanzos no está duplicada porque son tecnologías distintas. Lo más probable en su caso es que descargara el tar en vez del zip que es lo habitual y que este sea para una arquitectura diferente a la de su sistema operativo, por ejemplo un binario de 32 bits en vez del de 64. Conla informaicón provista no podría decirlo.

Comment: @JoseAngel y si intentas solamente `mvn.cmd` que sale?

Comment: No @RuslanLópez, no exsiten binarios específicos de Maven para arquitecturas o sistemas operativos (son los mismos binarios siempre). No obstante, la pregunta que compartí responde exactamente al mismo problema que tiene el OP, no importa que supuestamente ocurran con tecnologías diferentes. El problema está en el CMD de Windows, no en la tecnología. Es fácil comprobarlo: has lo contrario a lo que se indica y verás que tú también tendrás el mismo problema.

Comment: Abre el archivo mvn.cmd y la línea donde pone `@echo off` cámbialo por `@echo on` para ver si te indica la línea del error.

Comment: @E.Betanzos el problema en estos tars es que cuando uno trata de ejecutar maven al no ser una versión para windows no tiene mvn.exe sino un mvn sin extensión y en la consola al pedir mvn te da el archivo mvn en vez del mvn.cmd que trata de ejecutar el jar de maven. Realmente es un problema que le pasa a muchos por no verificar la plataforma y correrlo en powershell en vez de cmd

Comment: La salida es:        C:\Users\usuario>mvn.cmd

C:\Users\usuario>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPre

C:\Users\usuario>if exist "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.bat"

C:\Users\usuario>if exist "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "C:\Users\usuario\mavenrc_pre.cmd"

C:\Users\usuario>set ERROR_CODE=0
La sintaxis del comando no es correcta.

C:\Users\usuario>if not "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311
"=="" goto OkJHome

Comment: @RuslanLópez no existe un maven.exe. ¿Has probado usar el contenido del tar en Windows? Si lu hubieses hecho ya te habrías dado cuenta de que funciona correctamente puesto que es el mismo contenido que el zip. Y repito, no existe Maven para plataformas específicas, hay solo una distribución para todos los sistemas y arquitecturas.

Comment: @JoseAngel parece que tienes un problema en la definición de la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME. Quizá se te coló algún caracter no imprimible en la declaración (incluso se ve que al final te pone un espacio en blanco) y por esto falla el comando. Te sugiero que la borres a intentes crearla nuevamente introduciendo la ruta manuelmente o copiándola desde el Windows Explorer.

Comment: @E.Betanzos el problema era la versión de JDK utilizada, al cambiarlo a funcionado perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Ya ví que lo pudiste solucionar. De todos modos me cuesta creer que se tratase solamente de la versión, sigo pensando que el problema estaba en la definición de la ruta. Pero nada, enhorabuena!

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en la versión de JDK utilizada, utilizaba jdk1.8.0_31. Al cambiar la variable JAVA_HOME para utilizar jdk-17.0.1, se ha solucionado el problema.
Gracias por la ayuda, a todos los que han contribuido.